# Subset data frame that include a variable

Tags: r

I have a list of events and sequences. I would like to print the sequences in a separate table if event = x is included somewhere in the sequence. See table below:

```
    Event  Sequence
1     a       1
2     a       1
3     x       1
4     a       2
5     a       2
6     a       3
7     a       3
8     x       3
9     a       4
10    a       4
```

In this case I would like a new table that includes only the sequences where Event=x was included:

```
    Event  Sequence
1     a       1
2     a       1
3     x       1
4     a       3
5     a       3
6     x       3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Base R solution:**

```
d[d$Sequence %in% d$Sequence[d$Event == "x"], ]

   Event Sequence
1:     a        1
2:     a        1
3:     x        1
4:     a        3
5:     a        3
6:     x        3
```

---

**data.table solution:**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[Sequence %in% Sequence[Event == "x"]]
```

---

As you can see syntax/logic is quite similar between these two solutions:

- Find `event`'s that are equal to `x`
- Extract their `Sequence`
- Subset table according to specified `Sequence`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` to group the data and filter the sequence with any "x" in it.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Sequence) %>%
  filter(any(Event %in% "x")) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Event Sequence
  <chr>    <int>
1     a        1
2     a        1
3     x        1
4     a        3
5     a        3
6     x        3
```

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = "    Event  Sequence
1     a       1
                 2     a       1
                 3     x       1
                 4     a       2
                 5     a       2
                 6     a       3
                 7     a       3
                 8     x       3
                 9     a       4
                 10    a       4",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```